# How to install greenplum on windows?

Tags: greenplum

I have downloaded and installed greenplum loaders and client on windows but is it possible to install greenplum server on windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum Database is currently not supported on Windows.

More information can be found in the README.